# How can I redirect to login page with protected route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make a protected route. When there is no token in the Localstorage, it should be redirected back to the login page. For this, I created an array called dashboardRoutes. Using the map method, I sent these routes to the ProtectedRoute component and tried to check the token there. But I can only send login routes. Most likely I'm making a simple mistake but couldn't figure it out. Also please share if you have a more effective practice for protected routes. I have read a few articles and watched youtube videos but I haven't fully grasped it yet.

**App.js :**

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";
// import Login from "./layouts/Login/Login";
import dashboardRoutes from "./routes";
import NotFound from "./layouts/NotFound/NotFound";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        {dashboardRoutes.map((route, index) => (
          <ProtectedRoute {...route} key={index} />
        ))}
        {/* <Route
          exact
          path="/admin/dashboard"
          render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
        /> */}
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**ProtectedRoute.js :**

```
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = (route) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  if (route.needsAuth && !localStorage.token) {
    history.push("/")
  } else {
    return (
      <Route
        path={route.path}
        exact
        render={(props) => <route.component {...props} />}
      ></Route>
    );
  }
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**routes.js:**

```
import UserProfile from "views/UserProfile.jsx";
import TableList from "views/TableList.jsx";
import Typography from "views/Typography.jsx";
import Icons from "views/Icons.jsx";
import Admin from "./layouts/Admin.jsx"
import Maps from "views/Maps.jsx";
// import Notifications from "views/Notifications.jsx";
// import Upgrade from "views/Upgrade.jsx";
import Login from "layouts/Login/Login";

const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
    layout: "/",
    needsAuth: false,
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "pe-7s-graph",
    component: Admin,
    layout: "/",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "pe-7s-graph",
    component: Dashboard,
    layout: "/admin",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/user",
    name: "User Profile",
    icon: "pe-7s-user",
    component: UserProfile,
    layout: "/admin",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/table",
    name: "Table List",
    icon: "pe-7s-note2",
    component: TableList,
    layout: "/admin",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/typography",
    name: "Typography",
    icon: "pe-7s-news-paper",
    component: Typography,
    layout: "/admin",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/icons",
    name: "Icons",
    icon: "pe-7s-science",
    component: Icons,
    layout: "/admin",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
  {
    path: "/maps",
    name: "Maps",
    icon: "pe-7s-map-marker",
    component: Maps,
    layout: "/admin",
    needsAuth: true,
  },
];

export default dashboardRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `return <Redirect to="/login" />`.

Here is a great example of how to make a protectedRoute component.
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow